# Fullcalendar today one color and tomorrow one color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today date one color .. today date is `23-06-2018` so tomorrow calendar date color is green i want. see this demo link 23-06-2018 is background color is yellow so tomorrow to end of the calendar date background color is green

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2018-06-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2018-06-05',
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2014-09-15'
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
        // event.start is already a moment.js object
        // we can apply .format()
        var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
     }

});
```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/666uvdcj/1439/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the tomorrow date in the `eventRender` function and do the same thing as the coloring the events. 
You can try to get the date like the followings:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate()+1);
```

Then do the formatting for getting your `data-date` element.

```
var year = tomorrow.getFullYear
var month = ('0' + (tomorrow.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
date = ('0'+tomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2);
tomorrowString = tomorrow.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+date;
```

In the end, find your element and do the css for making it green.

```
$(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date='+tomorrowString+']').css('background-color','#AED581');
```

Here's my link: http://jsfiddle.net/fitrakun/Lukcajtd/

If you want to make it green for all of the next date, you can loop the date, format the date, and give the css.